# using cordova to send messages to webview for processing

Tags: java, javascript, android, cordova

I know how to send information from Javascript through a plugin up to Java for android to process accordingly.  I am trying to send information TO the client javascript via Cordova.

Cases:  A native button is clicked which i want to carry out some client side processing, execute some sort of method defined in javascript.

When looking around, i didnt seem to find what i was looking for, OR maybe i was just using the wrong keywords.

How i would i about execute an event chain such that it will fire an event *functionA();* in Javascript?

Comment: Have you displayed the native view that contains the button via a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know about Cordova but if you were planning to use it only to do this, you should know that you can easily execute a javascript instruction on the webView:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:functionA();");
```

You may also want to provide an interface between the javascript environment in the webView and your App itself, take a look at the addJavascriptInterface method of the WebView class

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: The purpose would be that there would be a page being shown.  I would not want to override the contents with a new loadUrl() call.  My purpose it to maybe do something similar to how you can call functions in Iframes?   maybe something like webView.contents().exec("this_Function();"); or something which would execute javascript inside the scope of the page.

Comment: unless of course, loadUrl will not actually reload, refresh, or otherwise disrupt the page.

Comment: A javascript:alert('Hello'); URI will not refresh the WebView, try it yourself on Chrome or Safari on this page, (Firefox requires real user interaction)

Comment: Thank you KKetch, Good thing to know! :)  I thought it would wipe the page and attempt a refresh.  I think i will use it.